# Determine the solution of congruence equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

how would we determine the solution of

> 4x≡1 (mod 27)

which is specifically negative and closest to 0. I know we first get the gcd, but what do we do after that?

Comment: Is the answer -6.5?

Comment: Use one of the linked methods (and subtract $27$ to make it negative if need be).

Comment: Come on! It's $x=7$